# Какой url возвращает deferrer deep link в facebook. IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, link, facebooksdk

По гайду facebook делаю defferer deep link, хочу подтянуть информацию по источнику инсталлов.
В IOS присутствует следующий метод:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] == nil) {
    [FBSDKAppLinkUtility fetchDeferredAppLink:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
      if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Received error while fetching deferred app link %@", error);
      }
      if (url) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
      }
    }];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Что содержит url? Какой Url он возвращает? Может кто пример скинуть?

Answer (score 0):

вот пример с [сайта](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking), урл такого плана будет `mytravelapp://tripId=SF`, вы сами должны настроить дип линк в консоли Facebook